# Database selection (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, database, selection

How do I choose a tbl_uploads table in the database?

PHPMYADMİN IMG

[image]

```html
<?php
$dbhost = "";
$dbuser = "";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "";
 
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die('cannot connect to the server'); 
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('database selection problem');
?>
```

Comment: You dont choose a table, you run a query on the table you want

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions. They are removed from PHP 7. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: I solved the problem thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to choose any table just fire the Query on the database in which the table exists, and you're done. For example,

```
<?php
    $dbhost = "";
    $dbuser = "";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "";

    mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die('cannot connect to the server'); 
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('database selection problem');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads;"
    //executing the query and printing it's results
    $results= mysql_query($query);
    print_r($results);
?>
```

This will print the results of query in the variable `$results`.

**Note :**

This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

- [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
- [PDO::query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Comment: Where is $results . and plz don't use mysql_* its deprecated

Comment: $results is a variable in holding the results of the query. Didn't you see that ? I also know that mysql_query() is depricated, but I mentioned it here just to set an example, but anyway thanks for telling me, I will add a note for that.

Comment: Ok fine, thanks for you comments. I respect your efforts and time.

Answer (score 0):

First, connect to your database (*keinotis_iletisim*). For example:

```
$dbhost = "localhost"; // or any other address
$dbuser = ""; // the user you created for the database in phpmyadmin
$dbpass = ""; // the password you created for the database in phpmyadmin
$dbname = "keinotis_iletisim";
```

Then, in a query you can mention a table, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads;
```

[Also see this link on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can select your table using sql statement like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyGuests";
$result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);
```

Now you can fetch the all records by using

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
     echo $row['column_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will work for you

```
<?php
//the connction

$hostname_localhost = "localhost";
$database_localhost = "keinotis_iletisim";
$username_localhost = "root";
$password_localhost = "";
$localhost = mysql_pconnect($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>


<?php


mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_record = "SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads";
$record = mysql_query($query_record, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($record);
$totalRows_record = mysql_num_rows($record);

//echo $row_record['tbl_uploads_table_colum'];

?>

<!--And if you want to display the list-->
<?php do { ?>

<?php echo $row_record['tbl_uploads_table_colum']; ?>

<?php } while ($row_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($record)); ?>
```